# pass a bound member function

Tags: c++, boost-function

I am trying to pass a bound member function into a routine and have the result type be determined by the template class:

```
template< class Fun, class P>
auto splat(double start, double finish, int steps,  Fun fun, double bias)
{
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(Fun) Fun_type;
    typedef boost::function_traits<Fun_type> function_traits;
    typedef boost::function_traits<Fun_type>::result_type P;
    vector<P> out = vector<P>(steps);
    double a = steps;
    a = a / 2;
    double step = (finish - start) / (steps - 1);
    double param = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        out[i] = fun(param);
        param += step*(1 + accel*(i - a - 1) / (a - 1));
    }
    return out;
}
```

The calling sequence is:

```
std::function<BallLib::Point(double)> pFun = std::bind(&BallPath::path, one, _1);
Point ppp = pFun(0.0);
vector<Point> line = testspread::splat(0.0, 3.1415, 10, pFun, 0.0);
```

It fails to compile with 
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line
Error   C2783   'std::vector> testspread::splat(double,double,int,Fun,double)': could not deduce template argument for 'P'

How do I get it to determine P?

Answer (score 1):

In your signature

```
template <class Fun, class P>
auto splat(double start, double finish, int steps, Fun fun, double bias);
```

You require a (non deducible) type `P` (that you don't use).

Change your code to

```
template <class Fun>
auto splat(double start, double finish, int steps, Fun fun, double bias)
{
    typedef BOOST_TYPEOF(Fun) Fun_type;
    typedef boost::function_traits<Fun_type> function_traits;
    typedef boost::function_traits<Fun_type>::result_type P;
    vector<P> out(steps);
    const double a = steps / 2;
    const double step = (finish - start) / (steps - 1);
    double param = start;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        out[i] = fun(param);
        param += step*(1 + accel*(i - a - 1) / (a - 1));
    }
    return out;
}
```

should fix your issue.

Comment: You could also do `using P = decltype(fun(double{})` to get the type P.

Comment: I tried that and got:

error C3779: 'spreadTest::splat': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined

I tried putting in vector<P> as the output, but then I got 15 random errors.

Comment: I allso tried:

 template <class Fun, class Out>
 Out splat(double start, double finish, int steps, Fun fun, double bias)
VS was unable to determine the return type.

Comment: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d7308f3cf1245c1) that works for gcc/clang. Your error seems to come from elsewhere.

Comment: It compiles without instantiating the class in Visual Studio.  Once its used (instantiated) the compiler fails.  Does C++ determine the return type just like it determines the function operatands?